# I can not seem to get information from page via xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently creating different projects to grasp the concept of web scraping. Currently I am trying to create a database of items from a shoe selling site, but I cant seem to get the data in text form.

I have tried.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy
import statistics
import pandas as pd

offset=0
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
listo=[]

while True:

    driver.get("https://stockx.com/sneakers?page={offset}".format(offset=offset))
    time.sleep(10)
    main_div=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div')

    for div in main_div:
        links=div.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

        for link in links:
            namer=(link.get_attribute('href'))
            print(namer)


            offset+=0.05

            listo.append(namer)
            namelist = sorted(set(listo))

            for hreflink in namelist:
                hreflinks=(hreflink)

                driver.get(hreflinks)
                time.sleep(10)

                
           
           
                LastsaleD=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="marketsummary"]/div[2]/div/div[1]
/div[1]')
                print(LastsaleD).text






    if offset>30:
        break
```

Comment: What Error exceptions?

Comment: May be because of this statement  `driver.get(testlink)` what is testlink?? by the way

Comment: I get the error has no text error. The testlink was just an error when copying the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Selenium is overkill and less efficient here. The data is found in json format within the `<script>` tags of the source html. Just do a simple request of the site, pull out the relevant `<script>` with the json, then parse the json into rows to put into a table.

Also, why increment `offset+=0.05`? I understand your logic of adding it for ever 20 items on the page, but why not just increment by `1` after that loop through the 20 items? What happens if for whatever reason you get 19 items returned or 21 items? Then your increments will be off for the rest of the loop.

Anyways, here's the code. This will get you going.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}
at_end = False

offset = 0
rows = []
while at_end == False:
    offset+=1
    url = "https://stockx.com/sneakers?page={offset}".format(offset=offset)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'})
    for script in scripts:
        jsonMatch = re.compile("{.*}")
        jsonStr = jsonMatch.search(str(script))[0]
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
        if jsonData['@type'] == 'OfferCatalog':
            break

    listings = jsonData['itemListElement']
    for listing in listings:
        item = listing['item']
        offers = item.pop('offers')
        item.update(offers)
        
        if item not in rows:
            rows.append(item)
        else:
            at_end = True
            continue
    print('Page: %s' %offset)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
              @type        brand  ... highPrice priceCurrency
0    AggregateOffer       Jordan  ...       165           GBP
1    AggregateOffer       Jordan  ...       226           GBP
2    AggregateOffer       Jordan  ...       321           GBP
3    AggregateOffer       Jordan  ...       159           GBP
4    AggregateOffer       Jordan  ...       190           GBP
..              ...          ...  ...       ...           ...
495  AggregateOffer         Nike  ...       230           GBP
496  AggregateOffer  New Balance  ...       159           GBP
497  AggregateOffer         Nike  ...       152           GBP
498  AggregateOffer         Nike  ...       162           GBP
499  AggregateOffer         Nike  ...       167           GBP

[500 rows x 14 columns]
```